# replace nth occurence of string in each line of a text file

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

I have large text files with space delimited strings (2-5). The strings can contain "'" or "-". I'd like to replace say the second space with a pipe.

What's the best way to go?

Using sed I was thinking of this:

```
sed -r 's/(^[a-z'-]+ [a-z'-]+\b) /\1|/' filename.txt
```

Any other/better/simpler ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add a number at the end of the substitute command. For example, the following will substitute the second occurrence of `old` with the string `new` on each line of `file`:

```
sed 's/old/new/2' file
```

So, instead of your proposed solution, you can use:

```
sed 's/ /|/2'
```

For more information, see e.g. [this sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8).

Comment: From the `sed` info file: *"Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the `g' and NUMBER modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across `sed' implementations.  For GNU `sed', the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the NUMBERth, and then match and replace all matches from the NUMBERth on."*

Comment: Info files... I hate them.  Anyway, I removed the ambiguous part. Good comment, +1.

Comment: Thanks, mrucci and Dennis. I thought that there must be something simple out there.

Comment: It seems every problem I have with text manipulation, I manage to solve with `sed`.  I'm not sure I should be thanking you for making `sed` even more useful to me, but I will anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try your version? Did it work? Because I think it is basically a good idea. I would do slightly differently, though:

```
sed -re 's/^([^ ]+ +[^ ]+) /\1|/'
```

This will accept any characters in a word that is not space, and will accept more than one spaces between the first two words.